# Reading CSV File - invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I have been using a rake file for a number of months to read in data from a CSV file.  I have recently tried to read in a new CSV file but keep getting the error "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8".  I have tried to manually work out where the problem is, but with little success.  The csv file is just text and URLs, there were a few unusual characters initially (where the original text had fancy bulletpoints) but I have removed those and cannot find any additional anomalies.

Is there a way to get round this problem automatically and identify and remove the problem characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution to discard all invalid utf8 bytes from a string :

```
ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
valid_string = ic.iconv(untrusted_string + ' ')[0..-2]
```

(taken from [this blog post](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Where abouts do you put these. I have something like this:

```
CSV.foreach("/Users/CarlBourne/Customers/Lloyds/small-test2.csv", options) do |row |

    name, workgroup, address, actual, output = row
    next if nbname == "NBName"
    @ssl_info[name] = workgroup, address, actual, output

    ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
    clean = ic.iconv(output + ' ')[0..-2]

puts clean

end
```

However it doesn't seam to work.